# C# Class De-initialization of Dynamic Memory

Tags: c#, constructor, destructor, idisposable

I am using a class that dynamically allocates an array during construction, as follows:

```
    class HeightMap
{
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private ulong numPixels;
    private float[,] value;

    public HeightMap(int width, int height)
    {
        if (width <= 0) throw new Exception("Invalid Dimension: Width");
        if (height <= 0) throw new Exception("Invalid Dimension: Height");

        // Make sure there is an uneven width and height (for allowing diamond square algorithm)
        if ((width % 2) == 0) width++;
        if ((height % 2) == 0) height++;

        this.numPixels = (ulong)(width * height);
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.value = new float[width, height];
    }


}
```

Am I required to implement `IDisposable` to release the `value` array on destruction, or is this automatically handled when the object is invalidated? [Anything else possibly wrong with this method of allocation in the constructor?]

Comment: I Guess you need not use IDisposable.GC should take care of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not Use IDisposable.They are generally used with Unmanaged Code.The Garbage Collector would take care of your Object Disposal.

Comment: So when a HeightMap object is set to null, the internal array is automatically reclaimed? C# is keeping track of all the dynamic member data?

Comment: It isn't so much that C# is keeping track of it.  It's more than C# *isn't* holding a reference anymore.  The GC will come along and free it later.

Comment: @user3830473 Setting null need not be the memory reclamation,Reclamation happens when your code is no longer referenced.Please read about Garbage Collector.It might help.

Answer (score 2):

You're allocating the memory through managed code.  You don't need to worry about it.